# Update broken in Ubuntu 14.04, install fail

Tags: update-manager

I get the following message: "The update information is outdated. This may be caused by network problems or by a repository that is no longer available. Please update manually by selecting 'Show updates' from the indicator menu, and watching for any failing repositories."

I click show updates and then I get the Software Updater window. There is no description of the update, all that shown is that 3.0 MB will be downloaded.

When I click "Install Now", I just get the same window as before, telling me that there is a 3.0 MB update available.

This update fails to install.

What can I do to remedy this? There is not even a technical description of what this update is.

Comment: Suggest you do `sudo apt update` in a terminal and see what errors show up. Edit your question to include the output. Then do `sudo apt upgrade` if no errors resulted from the first command.

Comment: Thank you so much Organic Marble! It tried the first command and didn't encounter any errors. After the second command my problem vanished. My Chrome browser also updated.  What joy! Now I can just sit back and use my pc without any concerns.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! I'll post my comment as an answer and you can accept it if you like by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: Sorry to say the same problem reoccurred. My Ubuntu system works well, these little error messages are just a bit annoying.

Comment: If you can post details of the error, someone can probably help out.  You likely just have a small problem with one of the software sources.

Comment: I think your right, it's probably something minor.  I did not get any errors when I used sudo apt update. At least Ubuntu Linux is easier than Windows 7. I have that on dual boot and I cannot fix windows to use the internet. Now I just use Ubuntu. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you do `sudo apt update` in a terminal and see what errors show up. Edit your question to include the output. Then do `sudo apt upgrade` if no errors resulted from the first command.